# Why am I regularly asked to prove that I am human?

Tags: support, bug

This StackExchange site is the only one that consistently asks me to prove that I am human, giving me some hard to read CAPTCHA to fill out. Usually I need to cycle through a few until I can decipher what I am supposed to enter.

I also noticed that (in Opera) the tag auto-suggestions have been broken for some time now (perhaps related).

Comment: Because your nick and avatar clearly indicate otherwise... :)

Comment: @jasonwryan: lol #avatar. Why does the nick indicate otherwise, though?

Comment: It's clearly a machine name; either you are the Terminator, or the Singularity has arrived...

Comment: Perhaps you do work too fast? In the beginning I had this problem when I quickly opened many questions in many tabs/windows and did them almost concurrently.

Comment: Turns out I am being asked because some script does not get "loaded" according to the SE-team.